# Does a power amplifier output constant current or constant voltage?

Tags: power, amplifier, constant-current, constant-power

I am having a confusion with the following a 16W [high power amplifier](http://www.minicircuits.com/pages/npa/ZHL-16W-43+_NPA.pdf) for an RF circuit.

Specifically I wonder, does it give me a constant current or a constant voltage as output?

and if it does neither, what does it do then?

Comment: Do you actually know what an RF amplifier is?

Comment: Since it's an amplifier it's not intended to output a constant of either - do you mean to ask if this is a current amplifier or a voltage amplifier?

Comment: If voltage or current were constant, were would be the amplified signal?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, the output would look like a voltage source with a pure resistance in series equal to the matching impedance (eg. 50\$\Omega\$ in this case- it is stated at the top of the datasheet).
[image]

Comment: I have always thought RF power amplifier are made to feed a 50Ω load but they do not have such an internal impedance. Do you think  this one is different since it is designed not for efficiency but to be laboratory tool which has to be able to feed more or less any load? Like a 50Ω function generator output?

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  The output of this will look something like a voltage source in series with or a current source parallel to a 50 ohm resistor.  Note that this picture may only be true within the operating frequency range of the amp, outside that it could look like a capacitor to ground or even a short to ground or something else depending on the precise construction of the output stage.

Answer (score 0):

Read specs more carefully.

- When output is saturated ( and distorted) Pout=16W and Pdc = 120W with 3W in.
- In the linear range spec is **Pout = 41dBm = 11dB**

  - ( above 0dB=1Watt or 30dBm=1000mW ) or **12.6W into 50 Ohm.**
- RF amps like this always assume matched linear impedance inputs and outputs=50 Ohms at test f.
  [image]